# How do I obtain a dynamic array and what do i dim it as? VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have recently started using arrays and have been very confused as to how it all works. The current array (subject to change) starts at D4. How do I go about loading the array correctly as I can't seem to use the array list to filter later on?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

```
   D
4 May
5 Ann
6 June


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim arrlist() As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("WorkingSheet")

lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
numr = lastrow - 3

ReDim arrlist(0, 1 to numr)

ws.Range("D4:D" & lastrow).Select

For c = 1 To numr
    arrlist(0, c) = CStr(Selection(c, 1).Value) 
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use `Range.Value` to set the `Array`.**

Change your code to this Simple version.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim arrlist() As Variant

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("WorkingSheet")

lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row

arrlist = ws.Range("D4:D" & lastrow).Value

'Additional Code
ReDim arr(1 To UBound(arrlist)) As Variant
For i = LBound(arrlist) To UBound(arrlist)
    arr(i) = arrlist(i, 1)
Next

wsd.Range($A$2:$AB$2260).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

**#NOTE:** *This will give you a 2-D array, so to print all the values from it, use*

```
For i = Lbound(arrlist) to Ubound(arrlist)
    Debug.Print arrlist(i,1)
Next
```

Just make sure to refer any element using `arrlist(i,1)` that `1` is important, otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: do I have to dim the arrlist as something else? as it pops up as "Type Mismatch" where `arrlist = ws.range....`

Comment: Yes, Dim it as Variant. Changed in the Answer

Comment: it works! thank you! However, when I've tried putting it into my filter it only takes the first array value, where wsd is the destination worksheet `wsd.Range($A$2:$AB$2260).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=arrlist, Operator:=xlFilterValues`

Comment: Try the additional Code. You should have mentioned in the Question that you want to use it in a Filter.

Comment: Thank you for the trouble! So a 2-D array would usually be used for reference and not particularly to use later?

Comment: It can be used. But Filter only takes a 1D array.